# Encrypt Folders

Tags: security, encryption, privacy

I seem to remember there being an option to encrypt my entire file system which I passed on but is there a way to just encrypt a folder / directory the way you can on Linux?

Comment: This question has been asked before, see [How do you encrypt a file or a single folder worth of data?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40082/how-do-you-encrypt-a-file-or-a-single-folder-worth-of-data)