# Determine if file or directory is encrypted?

Tags: macos, folders, filevault

I have FileVault enabled, so my home directory is encrypted. However, programs and libraries often use directories outside of `/home`; and [Disk Utility allows us to create encrypted files and directories](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/40082/83961) at arbitrary locations.

How can I tell if a file or directory is encrypted? Does Finder or a command line tool offer something?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: @Harv - I'm running OS X 10.8.5. But the question is more general. In the general case, I might do this from a shell script during an audit. And I'm interested in an Apple solution, and not arbitrary tools like Truecrypt (my bad, I should have stated that).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FileVault 2 (OS X Lion and newer), the entire boot partition will be encrypted, which includes your home folder as well as Applications.

I ran the following command and part of the output shows I am using an encrypted, unlocked volume:

```
ashley@sidekick-4:~$ sudo diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 2DDC5CBD-1B65-403E-9D4F-9424BC764433
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Time Machine Backups    2.0 TB     disk3s2
ashley@sidekick-4:~$
```

Comment: Thanks @Harv. Is there anything more granular than a volume? I'm interested in seeing if `/tmp` or `/opt` are encrypted.

Comment: @jww well, if the system is using OS X Lion or greater, and FileVault is enabled, the entire boot volume will be encrypted.  From terminal: $ diskutil info /dev/disk1 (for me that's my boot volume -- use diskutil list to see your volumes) shows lots of information about it.  At the bottom, you'll see info about whether it's a Core Storage Logical Volume, and whether that volume is encrypted.

Comment: @jww and, if they're using FileVault 1 (older than OS X Lion), then it's only the home folder that's encrypted.  The boot volume is "normal" with a sparsebundle for the users' home.  That gets unpacked on boot, so that when the user enters their password the sparsebundle opens and they have access to their files.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lion OS X uses [full disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption#Full_disk_encryption) for filevault2. Therefore it creates corestorage volumes on your disk and overwrites the entire contents with encrypted data. This encryption process takes a while, depending on your system speed. Only after that your disk is "secure".

You can see the partition's encryption status either in the System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Filevault. Or use the `diskutil corestorage list` command in Terminal. Look for the fields `Conversion Status` and `Fully Secure`. I had cases when the encryption was not successful but received no error message.

```
    > diskutil corestorage list
    CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
    |
    +-- Logical Volume Group XXX
        =========================================================
        Name:         10.8
        Status:       Online
        Size:         669162500096 B (669.2 GB)
        Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
        |
        +- Logical Volume Family XXX
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            Encryption Status:       Unlocked
            Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
            Conversion Status:       Complete
            Conversion Direction:    -none-
            Has Encrypted Extents:   Yes
            Fully Secure:            Yes
            Passphrase Required:     Yes
            |
            +-> Logical Volume XXX
                ---------------------------------------------------
                Disk:               disk1
                Status:             Online
                Size (Total):       668826951680 B (668.8 GB)
                Size (Converted):   -none-
                Revertible:         Yes (unlock and decryption required)
                LV Name:            XXX
                Volume Name:        XXX
                Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
```